# CSS Trapezium becoming triangle inside bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to have a trapezium with text inside a bootstrap modal but when I am trying to do the following I get a triangle instead of a trapezium. I want the trapezium to be responsive and in the center of the modal horizontally.

**HTML**

```
<div id="podium" class="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="podium">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title">Game Over!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span id="winnerSymbol" class="noughts">&#9711;</span>
                <img id="crown" class="crownNought" src="images/crown.png"/>
                <div id="wonText" class="box">WON</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wonText {
    border-left: 20vw solid red;
    border-top: 5vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5vw solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 10vw;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i tried out your code. it was a triangle because the height set was not enough for the trapezium to get formed. therefore it was a triangle. You have two solutions.

Increase the height of your wonText div.

```
height : 15vw //or more
```

Reduce the border width. the following dimensioins worked for me

```
border-left : 10vw solid red;
border-top : 3vw solid transparent;
border-bottom : 3vw solid transparent;
width: 0;
height : 10vw;
```

Comment: Ok, so now it works for me too. One more thing can I set a max-width to it?

Comment: i tried setting a max-width. this is the way i could do it. enclose the wonTextDiv with another div and set max-width on it. dont forget to set overflow-hidden to it as well.